# Preparing an activity before it starts problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio, android-activity

Basically, I have two activities: the first one is an empty activity with a rotating image which sleeps for 2 seconds then starts the second activity, the second activity has over 200 sounds in it. When it starts, a black screen shows up and my logcat starts typing "add sound:1 add sound 2 etc", and once it's done the activity starts.

Is there a way to make the first activity add the sounds while it sleeps before the second activity starts so the black screen won't appear?

I tried using a thread but didn't work

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
     public void run(){

     }
}).start();
```

Comment: The code snippet you posted doesn't show loading sounds in a thread. What did you actually try and how did it not work?

Comment: @TedHopp well i tried to write the files location for example R.raw.soun1, i also found this website androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1599 which has what i need but in part 2 where it sleeps for 1 second it gives me an error saying "The method Sleep(int) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}" –

Comment: The method is named `sleep()` (with a lower-case "s" -- not `Sleep()`). It is a `static` method of the `Thread` class, so you need to call it as `Thread.sleep(...)` if you're not calling it from a `Thread` subclass.

Comment: i'll look into that thanks alot!!